# Webpage does not center in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, centering

I have a web page:  http://www.lvdmonline.com  It looks fine and centered locally, but once published it is left justified.  I need to update it to be centered.

Help...thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in FireFox and IE9. It appears that you have no DOCTYPE tag, which is making IE render this in quirks mode. 
Read more on doctype tags here : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

To debug your page in IE9, press F12 when your page loads. You should see the IE developer toolbar appear at the bottom of the page. At the top of the bar, on the right hand ride you should see "Browser Mode: " and "Document Mode"...you want Document mode to display IE9 standards, NOT Quirks mode

Good luck